# Programming in a command file

Tags: file, unix, command

Need programming help.

Want to add current date to a command
tried this

```
date /t > stu.txt
call c:\Bin\MKS\sed -e 's/\//-/g' stu.txt | c:\Bin\MKS\cut -c5-14 >stu2.txt
```

not sure what to do here

then show current date on this command below

```
c:\Bin\7ZIP\7za.exe a -t7z c:\Bin\Test11-01-2013.7z @c:\Bin\TestList.txt
```

thanks my programming is very rusty.

Comment: Would it make more sense to get the date formatted correctly by the `date` command itself? What format do you want to get? For example `date +"%m-%d-%y"` will give `11-01-13` with no further editing. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/

Comment: Why is this tagged `unix`? Those filenames are obvious from Windows.

Comment: You might try `date +"%m-%d-%Y"` for `11-01-2013`, then assign that value to a shell variable.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that may answer your question (although with you having an odd mix of unix and Windows going there, I'm not sure this will work for you):

1) The output of `date` can be formatted directly: for example

```
date +"%m-%d-%Y"
```

will give

```
11-01-2013
```

2) You can get the output of a command inserted into another command by using backticks:

```
echo the year is `date +"%Y"`
```

would result in

```
the year is 2013
```

You can see how you could use that to insert your date string into a command; or you can put it in an environment variable first (handy if you have more than one place where you want to insert)

```
set myDate=`date +"%m-%d-%Y"`
echo $myDate
```

results in

```
11-01-2013
```

and you can include that in a file name (or any other command):

```
cat file_$myDate.txt
```

will expand to

```
cat file_11-01-2013.txt
```

You should be able to take these concepts and map them to what you are trying to do

Comment: Can't get the date + to work in windows 8 command file.  Maybe I didn't make it very clear.